# Viewers report on Google data studio (who saw my report)

Tags: looker-studio

We create approximately 60 dash boards for different stakeholders in our organisation for monitoring of various activities on #Google_data_studio. But we do not come to know does stake holders watches our analytical dashboards. Do we have any provision for it? If yes please let us know. We already tried this with Google Analytics but it shows only number of viewers and not exactly who have viewed the report.
If any one has tried please let us know. We are expecting following fields in viewers reports:

- Name of viewers
- At what time and on what day he saw the report ( to check frequency)
- how much time he spent on it.

Answer (score 1):

You can [measure report usage](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7410792?hl=en) by adding a Google Analytics Id to your report. If you have multiple reports, you can use the same id across all of them. The link has the step by step process for this. However, this won't show the name/identity of the report viewer.

Comment: Can this be applied to a template, such that every new report from that template is tracked with that ga ID? It will make it easier to track globally what people use and what errors they get.

Comment: By design, this is not supported. When a new report is created from a template, the Google Analytics Id is removed from the new report.

Comment: Hi Minhaz sir, We are pleased to see you are replying to our problem. We at paani Foundation use google data studio very extensively. For entire organisation at different levels of leadership we have different dash boards. We want above feature so that it will help us to infuse Data based decision making within organisation.